# Gmail Overriding font-family styles in tables

Tags: html, email, gmail

For example if I have:

```
<div style="font-family:'Trebuchet MS';">
    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tr>
            <td>Text 1</td>
            <td>Text 2</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Gmail's styles will override the font-family set in the div, even if I use !important. If I try to set the font right in the td elements like this:

```
<div style="font-family:'Trebuchet MS';">
    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tr>
            <td style="font-family:'Trebuchet MS';">Text 1</td>
            <td style="font-family:'Trebuchet MS';">Text 2</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Gmail strips the contents of the style attribute completely! The same thing happens if I try to add it to the table element, or a span within the td element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though it's not very standards-compliant, using the font tag allows you to get around this. For example:

```
<div style="font-family:'Trebuchet MS';">
    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tr>
            <td><font face="Trebuchet MS">Text 1</font></td>
            <td><font face="Trebuchet MS">Text 2</font></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Will work.